# Pivot or CTE to pivot/change date and time based data from rows to named columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, common-table-expression

```
SELECT 
    SerialNumber AS 'Serial', 
    ChannelName AS 'Channel', 
    CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE) AS 'ReadingDate', 
    CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME(0)) AS 'ReadingTime',
    ChannelValue AS 'Value'
FROM 
    [Staging].[UriData]
WHERE 
    ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM Staging.ActiveChannels)     
    AND Processed = 0   
ORDER BY 
    ReadingDate DESC, ReadingTime DESC
```

Output:

```
Serial  |  Channel  |  ReadingDate  |  ReadingTime  |  Value
--------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------
2209         m1         2018-09-20      16:30:00       20497
2209         m10        2018-09-20      16:30:00       20497
2209         m11        2018-09-20      16:30:00       1
2209         m2         2018-09-20      16:30:00       1
2209         m3         2018-09-20      16:30:00       2447
2209         m4         2018-09-20      16:30:00       0
2209         m5         2018-09-20      16:30:00       6490
2209         m6         2018-09-20      16:30:00       0
2209         m7         2018-09-20      16:30:00       50
2209         m7         2018-09-20      16:15:00       50
2209         m6         2018-09-20      16:15:00       0
2209         m5         2018-09-20      16:15:00       6620
2209         m4         2018-09-20      16:15:00       0
2209         m3         2018-09-20      16:15:00       2440
2209         m2         2018-09-20      16:15:00       1
2296         m11        2018-09-20      16:15:00       1
2296         m10        2018-09-20      16:15:00       20490
1489         m1         2018-09-20      16:15:00       20490
1489         m1         2018-09-20      16:00:00       20483
1489         m10        2018-09-20      16:00:00       20483
```

Pivot the table to produce:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Serial  |  Channel  |  ReadingDate  |  00:15  |  00:30  |  00:45.....00:00   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2209         m1         2018-09-20       56        987      65         234  
2209         m2         2018-09-20      etc.
2209         m3         2018-09-20     
2209         m4         2018-09-20      
2209         m5         2018-09-20      
1489         m6         2018-09-20      
1489         m7         2018-09-20      
2209.... etc.
```

Somebody helped me in a previous question that was answered, but I really do not understand what they have written and found it very complex. I don't want to just copy someone's code, but understand how this is achieved. While I have done a stack of tutorials, this outcome I require does not seem to be covered, or I am misunderstanding the principles.

[Previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247992/pivot-sql-table-by-date-name-and-value/52248216?noredirect=1#comment91444939_52248216)

There may be several different serial numbers, different channel names and differing dates. But there will always be 96 values for the day greater than midnight up until midnight (2018-01-01 00:01 to 2018-01-02 00:00).

So the new columns are the reading time filled with the corresponding value, by date, serial and channel. The initial query makes sure that the channels sent back exist in a table of channel names.

What do I use, some say CTE, some say Pivot, some have said to use SSIS. I am really struggling with the concept of this.

Any help, pointers or advice will be appreciated so I can focus my knowledge into that area.

Comment: CTE (for Common Table Expression), is a way to write sub-queries (and make them more easier to read), or is a way to do recursive queries.  In your previous example, the solution used recursive CTE.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: They also used Ranking function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
This is used to dynamically add rownumber, rank, ...  This was used to order the result.

Comment: They told they was used pivot.  This is not "real" pivot.  They build a dynamic query, specifying column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query used in @D-Shih [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248216/6305294) is an "[old style pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000)" query. Before SQL 2008 there was no [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) construct so an alternative approach was used that employed `GROUP BY`. This is still a valid approach in later versions of SQL Server although it is more verbose.

His query generates the "final query" that is then executed to give you a result. In your case you don't actually need to use a dynamic query but as you will see the final query is quite large and typing it out by hand will be a long and error prone exercise.

The way to understand what a bunch of statements do is to run them one at a time and see what the result is.

I will use @D-Shih [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248216/6305294) as an example.

Let's look at first CTE (Common Table Expression), which is also named CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST('00:00' AS TIME) startDt, CAST('23:45' AS TIME) endDt
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, startDt),endDt
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, startDt) <endDt
)
```

This is recursive Common Table Expression. You can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). To see what results the above statement produces you can simply add

```
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

right after it and run both statements to get:

```
startDt          endDt
---------------- ----------------
00:00:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
00:15:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
00:30:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
00:45:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
01:00:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
...
23:30:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000
```

From the above results you can see that `startDt` column has a set of "times".

Next we look at `TimeTable`. Notice that `TimeTable` CTE references "CTE" expression before it, so to see results you need to run them both followed by select query as follows:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST('00:00' AS TIME) startDt, CAST('23:45' AS TIME) endDt
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, startDt),endDt
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, startDt) <endDt
), TimeTable AS (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY startDt) rn 
    FROM (
       SELECT  startDt,endDt
       FROM CTE
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT CAST('23:45' AS TIME) startDt, CAST('23:45' AS TIME) endDt
    ) t1
)
SELECT * FROM TimeTable
```

You will get

```
startDt          endDt            rn
---------------- ---------------- --------------------
00:00:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000 1
00:15:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000 2
00:30:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000 3
00:45:00.0000000 23:45:00.0000000 4
...
```

Notice that `rn` (row number) column has been added. Notice that this column is a "sorting" column i.e. values in this column increase as `startDt` values increase.

Next you can run this query (note I have ommited CTE tables for brevity):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

[CTE Expression goes here]

select @cols = CONCAT(@cols,'MAX(CASE WHEN '''+CAST(startDt AS VARCHAR(5))+''' = CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME) THEN ChannelValue ELSE 0 end) AS ',QUOTENAME(CAST(startDt AS VARCHAR(5))),', ')
from TimeTable
WHERE startDt <= endDt
ORDER BY rn 

SET @cols = left(@cols, len(@cols) - 1)

-- Print value of a single variable
SELECT CAST('<A><![CDATA[' + CAST(@cols as nvarchar(max)) + ']]></A>' AS xml)
```

The complicated `CAST('<A><![CDATA[' + CAST(@cols as nvarchar(max)) + ']]></A>' AS xml)` is needed to work around SSMS text output truncation problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms))

Finally you can run the full query at once except you need to replace `exec(@query)` with `SELECT CAST('<A><![CDATA[' + CAST(@query as nvarchar(max)) + ']]></A>' AS xml)` to see the final query (note the text is XML encoded i.e. < is replaced with `&lt`; etc.)

You can also achieve the same result using [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) construct. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52435165/6305294) to your previous question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been a huge help. I have used the Pivot method and it works, but for one problem. Rather than the value appearing at the end of the '2018-09-20 00:00' row, the query creates a new row for the value at '2018-09-21 00:00'. Rather than having one row with 96 values for '2018-09-20 00:00', there are two rows, one with 95 for '2018-09-20 00:00' and one field null and one row with 95 nulls and 1 value at the end for '2018-09-21 00:00' http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/441a4/6/0

Comment: In your sample you have date and time columns as strings: `[ReadingDate] varchar(10), [ReadingTime] varchar(8)`, which is not optimal.

Comment: Use `CONVERT( DATE, ReadingDate, 103 ), CONVERT( TIME, [ReadingTime])` to convert them to `date` and `time` respectively.