# First value of tomorrow to appear on last cell of today's row

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot-table

Thanks to everyone's support on  Stack, I am getting close to solving my problem. But I have an issue with dates and times from a pivot in SQL.

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @_SerialNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)        
DECLARE @_DateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @_DateTo DATETIME


SET @_SerialNumber = '2209'
SET @_DateFrom = '2018-09-20 00:00'
SET @_DateTo = DATEADD(DD, 1, @_DateFrom)

SELECT [Serial], 
       [Channel],
       [ReadingDate],
       [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],[02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],
       [03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],[04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
       [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],[08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],
       [09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],[10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
       [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],[14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],
       [15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],[16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
       [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],[20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],
       [21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],[22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00]
--INTO [Staging].[PivotedData]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        SerialNumber AS [Serial],
        ChannelName AS [Channel],
        CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE) AS [ReadingDate],
        CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME(0)) AS [ReadingTime],
        ChannelValue AS [Value]
    FROM [Staging].[UriData]
    WHERE
        ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM Staging.ActiveChannels )
        AND ReadingDate > @_DateFrom AND  ReadingDate <= @_DateTo
        AND SerialNumber = @_SerialNumber
        AND Processed = 0
        AND ChannelName = 'm1'
    ) AS [Raw]
PIVOT
(
    MAX( [Value] ) FOR [ReadingTime] IN( [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],
                                         [02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],[03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],
                                         [04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
                                         [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],
                                         [08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],[09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],
                                         [10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
                                         [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],
                                         [14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],[15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],
                                         [16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
                                         [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],
                                         [20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],[21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],
                                         [22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00])
) AS pvt

ORDER BY ReadingDate DESC, Channel, [Serial]
```

The query produces the following results:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Serial | Channel | ReadingDate | 00:15 | 00:30 | 00:45 | 01:00 | 01:15  <--- ReadingTime --->   23:15 | 23:30 | 23:45 | 00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2209   |  m1     | 21/09/2018  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL          <---->           NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 20586
2209   |  m1     | 20/09/2018  | 20138 | 20140 | 20143 | 20145 | 20148         <---->           20580 | 20582 | 20584 | NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see from the query, I am requesting values between two times. I want midnight for the next day to appear on the row for the '2018-09-20' as the last set of readings are delivered at midnight. I receive the values that are from 23:45:00 to 23:59:59 at midnight. So I have 96 readings that are greater than '2018-09-20 00:00' and less than or equal to '2018-09-21 00:00'.

The expected result is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Serial | Channel | ReadingDate | 00:15 | 00:30 | 00:45 | 01:00 | 01:15  <--- ReadingTime --->   23:15 | 23:30 | 23:45 | 00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2209   |  m1     | 20/09/2018  | 20138 | 20140 | 20143 | 20145 | 20148         <---->           20580 | 20582 | 20584 | 20586
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As usual, thanks for your support.

Comment: can you post some data

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/441a4/6/0 - Is that what you meant?

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin How do you know which is your base date? For example this sample data is `20/09/2018 `

Comment: Is that depend on `where` clause?

Comment: Yes, as it has to run once a day. I will pass in today's date as a variable in a Sproc and add 1 day to that.  So I pass in for example '2018-09-20 00:00' then have a second variable with DATEADD(DD, 1, '2018-09-20 00:00'). This sets the scope of the dates I have to use.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin I would suggest you combine `ReadingDate` and  `ReadingTime` to one column for `datetime`

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin I write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let `ReadingDate` and `ReadingTime` combine into one column because There is a DateTime datatype in sql-server.

If you use two columns will be hard to use in condition.

Then you can use `CASE WHEN` set `ReadingDate` column check the data row is today or tomorrow if is tomorrow set the today in the row.

before your pivot query.

```
 SELECT [Serial], 
       [Channel],
       [ReadingDate],
       [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],[02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],
       [03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],[04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
       [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],[08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],
       [09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],[10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
       [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],[14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],
       [15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],[16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
       [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],[20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],
       [21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],[22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Serial AS [Serial],
        Channel AS [Channel],
        (CASE WHEN CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE) > CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
            THEN CAST(@_DateFrom AS DATE) 
            ELSE CAST(ReadingDate AS DATE)
         END)  AS [ReadingDate],
        CAST(ReadingDate AS TIME) AS [ReadingTime],
        Value AS [Value]
    FROM UriData
     WHERE ReadingDate > @_DateFrom  AND ReadingDate <= @_DateTo  AND Serial = '2209'   
    ) AS [Raw]
PIVOT
(
    MAX( [Value] ) FOR [ReadingTime] IN( [00:15],[00:30],[00:45],[01:00],[01:15],[01:30],[01:45],[02:00],
                                         [02:15],[02:30],[02:45],[03:00],[03:15],[03:30],[03:45],[04:00],
                                         [04:15],[04:30],[04:45],[05:00],[05:15],[05:30],[05:45],[06:00],
                                         [06:15],[06:30],[06:45],[07:00],[07:15],[07:30],[07:45],[08:00],
                                         [08:15],[08:30],[08:45],[09:00],[09:15],[09:30],[09:45],[10:00],
                                         [10:15],[10:30],[10:45],[11:00],[11:15],[11:30],[11:45],[12:00],
                                         [12:15],[12:30],[12:45],[13:00],[13:15],[13:30],[13:45],[14:00],
                                         [14:15],[14:30],[14:45],[15:00],[15:15],[15:30],[15:45],[16:00],
                                         [16:15],[16:30],[16:45],[17:00],[17:15],[17:30],[17:45],[18:00],
                                         [18:15],[18:30],[18:45],[19:00],[19:15],[19:30],[19:45],[20:00],
                                         [20:15],[20:30],[20:45],[21:00],[21:15],[21:30],[21:45],[22:00],
                                         [22:15],[22:30],[22:45],[23:00],[23:15],[23:30],[23:45],[00:00])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ReadingDate DESC, Channel, [Serial]
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a07486bef8626ab64e60a23a4808f0f8)

Comment: Wow, that really works well! What are you saying in the CASE statement that adds the value at the end? I'm a C# developer and struggle to get my head out of that and into SQL. Thanks again, you have been more than generous!

Comment: Here is a link about `CASE WHEN` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.In short  `CASE WHEN` can write a `if...else` in the row.

Answer (score 1):

I see a `<=`sign which include the upper bound (next day).

Maybe this can be changed?

`AND ReadingDate > @_DateFrom AND  ReadingDate <= @_DateTo`

Comment: I have tried casting a new date, but it sees anything at midnight as the same day and not tomorrow if that makes sense.